# Add IAP to my app: missing section under "App Store""?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add an in-app purchase to my (already existing and published) app. I have already created the IAP:

[image]

[image]

Then I created a new iOS version of my app (containing the IAP operations), submitted it to Apple, which has been accepted and now is pending developer release.

Also, in "In-app purchases" under "Features", there is this message from Apple:

[image]

However, under "App Store" I just can't see any "In-app purchase" section :

[image]

So, what am I missing?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to submit the IAPs shown in your first screen shot and then submit the new version of the app.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! I finally got it right.